# Scaling APScheduler

Tags: python-2.7, distributed, scheduler, apscheduler

I want to run multiple instances of APScheduler pointing to one common persistent job DB. Is it possible to run in that way?? I also mean that the jobs in the DB get shared among the Scheduler instances and at a point there is only one instance executing a scheduled job.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an old question but I'll answer it anyway. No, it's not (yet) possible to run APScheduler in that manner yet due to lack of a synchronization/locking mechanism to that end.

Comment: Hei Alex. It has been a year and ver 3 was released was that support added in any way and how to use it?

Comment: There is no such support. I'm not sure when or if it will be added.